How can add the positional argument :UnitedStates.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'm'?
In the article "Automating Option Pricing Calculations",https://sanketkarve.net/automating-option-pricing-calculations/,chapter "Calculation of Implied Volatility via Stock Prices":
from QuantLib import *
valuation_date = Date(20,11,2020)
Settings.instance().evaluationDate = valuation_date
calendar = UnitedStates()

It get the type error info:
TypeError: UnitedStates.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'm'

How can add the  positional argument then?

https://quantlib-python-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dates.html#calendar indicates there are several possible calendars associated with the United States, and that you need to specify which you want. It's possible this change was made after the article was written.

It's interesting that QuantLib.UnitedStates() requires a market (e.g., QuantLib.UnitedStates.FederalReserve) yet QuantLib.UnitedKingdom() does not. I can't see anything in the documentation that explains this apparent anomaly
